# Why does typescript allow accessing a non existing property when accessing an object with a variable

Tags: typescript

```
const obj = {
   a: 5
} as const

obj.b ----> error

const key = "b"
obj[key] ----> no error
```

Why doesn't typescript block accessing a non existing property which will result in a runtime error? In the example above `key` is inferred by typescript as a literal "b"

Comment: This is since I had "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors" in my tsconfig.

Answer (score 2):

Whether TypeScript reports this as an error or not, depends on the compiler settings you have configured. If you turn on the `strict` option (or at minimum `noImplicitAny`), it will report it as an error.

[Playground with `noImplicitAny == false`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAsAKBnghgFwwCsOAvjPhDKJFDjgogHTwwD0HMAtHzwD4YAUwBOokKMbY60GAGthAT1QwARPDVMkAbUVKAup279BMMCBHjJQA)

[Playground with `noImplicitAny == true`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAsAKBnghgFwwCsOAvjPhDKJFDjgogHTwwD0HMAtHzwD4YAUwBOokKMbY60GAGthAT1QwARPDVMkAbUVKAup279BI8ZKA)

Comment: This is since I had "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors" in my tsconfig.